# How can i include a foreign key field in the "fields" tuple to make it appear on detail view page in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

**Models:**
I have a model like this

```
class TestModel1(models.Model):
    bookingid = models.ForeignKey(paymenttable)            // foreign key
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, db_index=True)

    // I want this to be displayed in both the list view and detail view
    @property
    def custom_field(self):
       return self.bookingid.username
```

**Admin.py**

```
class MyAdmin(ReadOnlyAdminFields,admin.ModelAdmin):

      // this works and i get custom_field in list view
      list_display = ('custom_field', 'name') 
      readonly = ('custom_field', 'name')

      // this dosent work and gives error  
      fields = ('custom_field', 'name')
```

Error: Unknown field(s) custom_field. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of MyAdmin class

Comment: For `fields` try `fields = ('bookingid__username', 'name')`

Comment: @wfehr , yes tried this , got the same error - Unknown field(s) bookingid__username. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of MyAdmin class

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo. `readonly` should be `readonly_fields`

A little hack, you can add a custom label with `short_description` property to your `custom_field` method. You can do it like this...

```py
# models.py

class TestModel1(models.Model):
    bookingid = models.ForeignKey(paymenttable)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, db_index=True)

    @property
    def custom_field(self):
       return self.bookingid.username

    custom_field.short_description = "User"
```

Then you can use it in your list of fields in your admin class like this...

```py
# admin.py

class MyAdmin(ReadOnlyAdminFields,admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ('custom_field', 'name') 
      readonly_fields= ('custom_field', 'name')
      fields = ('custom_field', 'name')
```

Comment: This is working if i use readonly_fields= ('name', 'custom_field') .
But if I want to make only the custom_field as readonly - readonly_fields= ('custom_field')
then its giving the same error. This looks wierd

Comment: Ok i missed the comma - readonly_fields= ('custom_field' , ) . This worked fine
Also to use the custom_field.short_description = "User" , I had to remove @property, any idea about this ?